# linkages not updating when the referenced the cell is changed programatically

Tags: excel, vba, apache-poi

I have a cell A in one of the sheets referencing another cell B in another sheet. Links are set to updat autmatically. Everytime I change the value in Cell B, Cell A reflect the change as expected.

However, if I change the value of Cell B from out side excel (using Java POI apache api) then Cell A does not change. I open the sheet and Cell A still reflects the old value. If I do a recaluclate, same thing.

Any idea how to make this value update/change to reflect the new cell?

Please help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929327/excel-formula-not-updating-cell?rq=1 might help.

Comment: Yes it did.... Thank you so much. I searched alot and didnt get that thread. Put it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: see posted answer. Felt like copy paste job from others answer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

way 1.
You can re-evaluate all formula cells by:

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)
```

or

```
HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook)
```

way 2.

```
wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll()
```

or

```
wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)
```

**Ref link**:

SO link: [Excel Formula Not Updating Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929327/excel-formula-not-updating-cell?rq=1)

Apache link: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html

**Credit should goes to following users**:

[akokskis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697281/akokskis) and 
[eugen-constantin-dinca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153861/eugen-constantin-dinca) and
[nilamber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846431/nilamber)

Other links:

Apache link:[Interface FormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html)

Apache link:[Class HSSFFormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFFormulaEvaluator.html)

Apache link:[Class XSSFFormulaEvaluator](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFormulaEvaluator.html)

SO link:[apache-poi-evaluate-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716664/apache-poi-evaluate-formula)